# close for text file causing segmentation fault and `glibc detected` under linux in C++

Tags: c++, linux, text, segmentation-fault, glibc

I have a log class, that class contains a stream defined as:`ofstream logfile` and a mutex to make sure that each time only one thread writes to the file (the program is multi-threaded).
The class is defined as:

```
#define LOG_NAME "log.txt"

using namespace std;

class Log
{
private:
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_write;
    ofstream logfile;

public:
    Log();
    ~Log();
    void Write (string txt);
};
```

The constructor is:

```
Log::Log()
{
    pthread_mutex_init (&mutex_write,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_write);
    logfile.open(LOG_NAME, ios::out | ios::trunc);
    logfile << "Created log file named " << LOG_NAME << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_write);
}
```

The destructor is:

```
Log::~Log()
{
    logfile << "Closing log file" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_write);
    logfile.close();
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_write);
    pthread_mutex_destroy (&mutex_write);
}
```

and:

```
void Log::Write (string txt)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex_write);
    logfile << txt << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex_write);
}
```

In some of the times when the destructor is called, it can't execute the line `logfile.close();` because it says that it gets a segmentation fault, or it displays the message:

```
*** glibc detected *** corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000000513eb0 ***
Abort
```

This doesn't happen all the time, it seems to be happening randomly, at about 10% of the time. The program is multi-threaded (under linux).

**Edit:**
example of usage: (where `log` is a pointer to an object of `Log` class)

```
stringstream str;
str.str("");
str << "Ant " << i << " was created at place: (" << x << "," << y << ")";
log->Write (str.str());
```

or, if the string contains only knows text

```
log->Write ("Created board entity");
```

Comment: How it this Log object used in the threads? I assume it's a shared object. Can you provide us with some code showing how the calls to Write() look?

Comment: Why have you got lock protection in your destructor?  Either, nothing should be using the Log object at that point, or you've got bigger problems to worry about...

Comment: @forsvarir, I've added the protection in the destructor just in case, Because we were already putting mutexes every where.

Comment: Heap corruption like this is usually a result of a bug somewhere *before* the code where the `abort` happens.

Comment: Use an ostringstream, not  a stringstream.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, does using `stringstream` instead of `ostringstream` is what causing the problem?

Comment: @Iilya I don't know, but using stringstream correctly is more difficult than using ostringstream, if you only need an output stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we have a problem with checking that all threads have finished. We have repaired this, and now it works fine.
The problem probably happened because other threads tried to access a closed file, and sometimes tried to access a killed entity.

Comment: Since issue was found - short questions. Is log global static object? Why not to use one of working c++ logging frameworks in your project?

Comment: @Sergey: First, I wasn't aware that there are existing logging frameworks in C++.
Second, as you can see the log class I've written is very simple and easy to write. We had no bugs with it (except for this one, which is a bug with the threading of other parts and not with the log itself). We would have had to put more work into learning how to use an existing class than write this one.

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure, but it can be related to memory corruption anywhere in code.
To dig this issue deeper, try run your program under Valgrind or by investigating core dump (be sure that it enabled - AFAIR ulimit -c unlimited).